# Querying for ae matches æ in SQL Server / LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008

When I try running...

`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = 'ae'` it returns matches where the username is æ (ash character).

I was wondering if there's a way to support characters like the ash character but get an **exact** match for what I'm looking for.

I'd like to search for ae and get just ae, not ae and æ

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: perhaps I'm not getting what you're after. Did you want to have instances of `ae` be considered two characters `ae` AND the single character `æ`?

Comment: @p.campbell when I search for ae I just want the literal ae and not have it match æ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to happen with SQL collations

```
;with Users As
(
select 'æ' as Username UNION ALL SELECT 'ae'
)
SELECT *
FROM Users WHERE Username = 'ae' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: When I was able to reproduce your example, but not use it in my application, I started playing around. If you prefix your strings with `N`, the code will break. So apparently it has something to do with `VARCHAR` versus `NVARCHAR` too. Can anyone explain that (or point to a resource)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ordinal collation for your comparison. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE Username = 'ae' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
```

Comment: This makes the query case-sensitive, is there anyway to have both?